# Putting imported tacks into an album

Tags: itunes, music, import, album

I just imported music from some CD's I had, and iTunes put each track into a single album. How do I put all the tracks into 1 album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to select the tack and press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, this will allow you to edit the album. Give the album a name. After that, you change the name of each album (track) to the first one you chose When you name it the track will be added to the first album and become an individual track in the album.